# exit excel session from Access VBA without saving

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have been looking for a solution of exiting excel using vba and kill it's processus, but I still can't find  any solution, the methods discussed in here are about hiding the saving prompt, but how can I exit an excel application (not only the instance) without saving and of course, stop its execution?
Thank you

Comment: Why is this tagged "access" if you're talking about Excel?

Comment: im in fact using all this in access, I'm opening the excel application using vba and getting some data out of it to my tables

Comment: Ohh and you didn't think it was relevant to mention that??  I assumed you were doing it all from within Excel based on your question, because you didn't say otherwise.

Comment: well it changes almost nothing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will hide the prompt and close without saving

```
Sub CloseActiveBook()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Or force it

```
Sub Auto_Close()
ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
End Sub
```

This example closes Book1.xls and discards any changes that have been made to it.

```
Sub saveWNoChanges ()
Workbooks("BOOK1.XLS").Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: **ThisWorkbook.Saved = True**     saves the file ?

Comment: @TarikKaoukab no, it marks the file as "saved" even when it isn't so that you are not prompted to save

Comment: @TarikKaoukab
Because the Saved property is set to True, Excel responds as though the workbook has already been saved and no changes have occurred since that last save. [check this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213428)

Comment: great, I get the idea, but it says that the method thisworkbook.save has failed

Comment: @TarikKaoukab added another ex

Comment: I Found the answer and I just posted it, thanks a lot @Krib

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to do this.  First, set the display alerts to false. Second, set the save state to true.  Both are equivalent, though the second will require a loop if multiple workbooks are open, so the first is recommended (and included below)

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Quit
```

Comment: @RGA I did try that, but the processus are always there...and I'm using multiple workbooks

Comment: @TarikKaoukab what do you mean by "processes are always there"?

Comment: I still can see the EXCEL proccessus in task Manager

Comment: I am having the same problem. It appears to be limited to .xls files. I have no problem using either the DisplayAlerts option or SaveChanges:=False option with later versions of Excel, such as .xlsm or .xlsx.

Answer (score 0):

Combining with what Mr.krib has said, ThisWorkbook.Saved = True is working if you change **ThisWorkbook** to the **name_of_your_instance_Excel.ActiveWorkbook**
for example:

```
Set myxl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
myxl.ActiveWorkbook.saved= True
```

P.S: It works for multiple workbooks as well!

Thank you @Krib

Comment: Glad to help. You can show your appreciation by accepting the answer ;)